# What is this keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, computer-science, symbols, device, keyboard-layout

[hp probook 450 g3 keyboard azerty layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAero.jpg)
Hello everyone, I have an HP Probook 450 G3 laptop with an AZERTY keyboard with an unknown layout (see image). There are keys with 4 symbols and I cannot activate the symbols < and > for programming. Under Windows I do Alt + 60 (<) and Alt + 62 (>) works well and under Linux no combination works. I even tried a few random arrangements, but nothing worked. Someone to help me please?

Comment: The `<` and `>` keys are on the right of the space bar, a row up. Try using them with SHIFT or SHIFT+FN held down. I've seen AZERTY keyboards in France.

Comment: I tried SHIFT and SHIFT + FN but nothing works. As you have seen there are 4 symbols on some keys. Yes it's an AZERTY French but this type of AZERTY is not common for me.

Answer (score 0):

Which alt are you pressing down? To me instinct would be the left Alt for one symbol and the right alt for the other symbol like ive seen on some weird QWERTY keyboards, but I could be way off lol. What language are you using on the OS? French or a derived french language like Canada's french?

Comment: I use ALT left and ALT right but nothing can enable the fourth symbol as you can see on keyboard. I use French (France)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install keyboard layout in the OS settings that corresponds to your hardware keyboard. It should map these HID buttons to characters you want:

```
UsagePage 0x07 UsageID 0x36 - Keyboard Comma
UsagePage 0x07 UsageID 0x37 - Keyboard Period
UsagePage 0x07 UsageID 0x38 - Keyboard QuestionMark
```

There is [XKeyCaps](https://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/) that may help you to select proper keyboard layout.